# redirect a page with parameters and without page extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect a page like this:

```
http://example.com/clients/themes?domain=localhost.com
```

this link should be redirected to skin.php which is in the same directory.

Can any one help me? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to redirect to `http://example.com/clients/skin.php?domain=localhost.com` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^domain=localhost\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^clients/themes/?$ clients/skin.php? [L,NC]
```

This will internally forward your request to `/clients/skin.php` stripping out query string. If you want query string as well then remove `?` after `skin.php`.